# partial derivative of a polynomial belongs to a maximal ideal

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

If we consider an affine space $\mathbb{A}_K^n=\mathrm{Spec}\,K[T_1,\cdots,T_m]$ over a field $K$. It's easy to show that $T_x\mathbb{A}_K^n\simeq K^n$ where $x$ is a $K$-point corresponding to the maximal ideal of the form $(T_1-x_1,\cdots,T_n-x_n)$. But I wonder how to show that $\dim T_x\mathbb{A}_K^n=n$ (or maybe fail to equal) for a general closed point correspond to a general maximal ideal $\mathfrak m$.

I tried to consider the map $\mathfrak m\to \kappa(x)^n,\,g\mapsto(\frac{\partial g}{\partial T_1}(x),\cdots,\frac{\partial g}{\partial T_n}(x))$. If $x$ is $K$-point, it's easy to show that the kernel is $\mathfrak m^2$, and induced a bijection: $\mathfrak m/\mathfrak m^2\to \kappa(x)^n=K^n$. But in the general case, is that right? I think it's just a injection. This is equivalent to prove the following:

> **Conjecture**: If $g\in\mathfrak m$ and we have $\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial T_i}\in\mathfrak m$ for all $i$, then $g\in\mathfrak m^2$.

If $\mathfrak m=(T_1-x_1,\cdots,T_n-x_n)$, it is verified by Taylor expansion. But for general maximal ideal, I don't know how to do it.

Comment: @baharampuri  The $f$ seems not contained in $\mathfrak m$.

Comment: Sorry missed that.

Comment: One clarifying question: which field are you considering $T_x\Bbb A^n_K$ as a vector space over when you ask for its dimension? If you ask over the residue field at $x$, the answer is always $n$, whereas if you ask over the field $K$, the dimension is $n$ times the degree of the residue field as an extension over $K$.

Comment: @KReiser $T_x\mathbb A_K^n$ considered as  a $\kappa(x)$-vector space.  May I ask how to prove that the dimension is $n$?